# Adding SideBar Button making my array nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm actually not quite sure how this is possible. For I have debugged through my application and have found that my array is in fact NOT nil, but for some reason whenever I add this code to my viewDidLoad:

```
 _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];
_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);


[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

I get SIGABRT error telling me

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

So...I'm not sure how this is possible, and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas. My array is a simple NSMutableArray that I init and allocate in my viewDidLoad, and then I load it with objects as such:

```
    placesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

[placesArray addObject:@"ATM"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Park"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Restaurant"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Library"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Gas Station"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Florist"];
[placesArray addObject:@"Cafe"];
```

So anyway, I'm still wondering how I can fix this. All help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: which line does throw the exception exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The array in the error message is probably the gesture recognizer array in `self.view`.  Which is to say that `self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer` is probably nil.